# Ability to lock computer for productivity

Tags: lock-screen

Is there a program similar to this for ubuntu https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tomka.lockmyphone ?

This app locks the phone for selected periods of time during selected intervals.

Or is there a shell script already out there? I'm not sure how shell scripts work.

I searched this forum and found brainbreak. But it seems to be defunct now.

=== **EDIT** ===

The solution should be such that it can't be circumvented and locks the screen for sure for a predetermined amount of time at predetermined intervals.

Comment: It would be great if you edit your question to explain what that app does.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Thank you for pointing that out, I've made the changes now.

Comment: I am not sure if such a software is available in Ubuntu. It may be simpler to turn off the computer instead and unplug it from power, so that you would have to put some effort to use it once again.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi will a shell script which logs out the logged in user for a set interval do?

Comment: I don't know how to write that shell script (you can edit your question accordingly, and someone will certainly answer). However, you will probably be able to log in immediately after being logged out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to adapt existing application named [WorkRave](https://workrave.org/) for your needs.

Its original purpose is

> Repetitive Strain Injury prevention tool

but it provides functionality to set [time intervals and warnings](https://workrave.org/about/).

You can install it as [normal package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/workrave) from the repository:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install workrave
```

Comment: Hi N0rbert, thank you for the suggestion. I wanted to clarify I want a solution that can't be circumvented and locks the screen for sure. I should've mentioned that earlier. I'll update my question now.